# Error: 121 “Duplicate key on write or update” - MySql

Tags: mysql

Error consulta SQL:

Tengo problemas a la hora de insertar las claves FK este script funciona hasta crear la base de datos pero para insertar las claves FK marca error.

Error
consulta SQL: Copiar

-- Referencia usuario --> lista
ALTER TABLE usuario ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_usuario15 FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES lista (id_usuario) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1005 - No puedo crear tabla `ls_musica`.`usuario` (Error: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")

Aqui les dejo el script de mi consulta:

```html
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ls_musica DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' DEFAULT COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci';
use ls_musica;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persona(
    id_persona INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    apellido1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    apellido2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    dni VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_persona)
);

-- TABLA Grupo

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Grupo(
    nombre_grupo VARCHAR(50),
    año_creacion INT,
    año_separacion INT,
    estilo_musical VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (nombre_grupo)
    
);


-- TABLA usuario

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario(
    id_usuario INT UNSIGNED,
    mail VARCHAR(50),
    num_cuenta VARCHAR(22),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_usuario)
  
);


-- TABLA lista

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lista(
    id_usuario INT UNSIGNED,
    nombre_lista VARCHAR(50),
    descripcion VARCHAR(50),
    fecha_creacion DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_usuario, nombre_lista)
);


-- TABLA lista_cancion

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lista_cancion(
    id_usuario INT UNSIGNED,
    nombre_lista VARCHAR(50),
    id_cancion INT UNSIGNED,
    fecha_insercion DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_usuario, nombre_lista, id_cancion)
);


-- TABLA cancion

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cancion(
    id_cancion INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    titulo VARCHAR(50),
    segundos_duracion INT UNSIGNED,
    calificacion INT,
    es_single BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'cierto',
    nombre_grupo VARCHAR(50),
    id_artista INT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_cancion)
);


-- TABLA grupo_artista

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grupo_artista(
    nombre_grupo VARCHAR(50),
    id_artista INT UNSIGNED,
    es_lider BOOLEAN,
    PRIMARY KEY (nombre_grupo, id_artista)
    
);

-- TABLA artista

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS artista(
   id_artista INT UNSIGNED,
   sobrenombre VARCHAR(50),
   fecha_nacimiento DATETIME,
   fecha_muerte DATETIME,
   fortuna INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (id_artista),
   UNIQUE (sobrenombre)

); 

-- TABLA usuario_cancion

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario_cancion (
    id_reproduccion INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_usuario INT UNSIGNED,
    id_cancion INT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_reproduccion)
     
);


-- Referencia usuario --> lista
ALTER TABLE usuario ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_usuario FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES lista (id_usuario) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
 
 -- Referencia lista --> usuario
ALTER TABLE lista ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_lista1 FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuario (id_usuario) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;

 -- Referencia usuario_cancion --> usuario, cancion
ALTER TABLE usuario_cancion ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_usuario_cancion1 FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuario (id_usuario) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE usuario_cancion ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_usuario_cancion3
FOREIGN KEY (id_cancion) REFERENCES cancion (id_cancion) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;


-- Referencia lista_cancion --> lista, cancion
ALTER TABLE lista_cancion ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_lista_cancion1 FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario, nombre_lista) REFERENCES lista (id_usuario, nombre_lista) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE lista_cancion ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_lista_cancion2
FOREIGN KEY (id_cancion) REFERENCES lista (id_cancion) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;


-- Referencia cancion --> grupo, artista
ALTER TABLE cancion ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_cancion1 FOREIGN KEY (nombre_grupo) REFERENCES grupo (nombre_grupo) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE cancion ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_cancion2
FOREIGN KEY (id_artista) REFERENCES artista (id_artista) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;

-- Referencia grupo_artista --> grupo, artista
ALTER TABLE grupo_artista ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_grupo_artista1 FOREIGN KEY (nombre_grupo) REFERENCES grupo (nombre_grupo) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE grupo_artista ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_grupo_artista2 FOREIGN KEY (id_artista) REFERENCES artista (id_artista) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 0):

El único error que me da tu dataset es en esta línea:

```
ALTER TABLE lista_cancion
  ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_lista_cancion2
  FOREIGN KEY (id_cancion) 
  REFERENCES lista (id_cancion) 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Que entiendo que debería poner:

```
ALTER TABLE lista_cancion
  ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_lista_cancion2
  FOREIGN KEY (id_cancion) 
  REFERENCES cancion (id_cancion) 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

La que no termino de ver muy clara es esta restricción:

```
ALTER TABLE usuario
  ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_usuario
  FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario)
  REFERENCES lista (id_usuario)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

¿Para qué únicamente permites crear usuarios que ya existen en la tabla `lista`? ¿No debería ser al revés?

Con respecto al error que comentas, ¿ya has hecho algún `INSERT`?